# HttpErrorResponse: Http failure response for api url jasmine test

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine

I'm having difficulties in testing an api call and returning an error

" HttpErrorResponse: Http failure response for https://server.herokuapp.com/twitter/gettweets: 0"

I can get it to return correct results fine

I'm basically getting tweets and displaying within the app

The service I'm testing:

```
const TWITTER_KEY = makeStateKey('twitter');
@Injectable()
export class SocialService {
  private twitter:any;
  private url = 'https://server.herokuapp.com/';
  constructor(private http: HttpClient,
              @Inject(PLATFORM_ID) private platformId,
              private transferState:TransferState) { }

  initTwitter(){
    this.twitter = this.transferState.get(TWITTER_KEY, null as any);
    let data;
      if (this.twitter) {
        data = this.transferState.get(TWITTER_KEY, null);
        console.log("data= "+data);
            this.transferState.remove(TWITTER_KEY);

            return Observable.of(data);
            }else{
              const httpOptions = {
                headers: new HttpHeaders({
                 'Content-Type': 'application/json',
               })
             };
              return this.http.get(this.url+'twitter/gettweets', httpOptions)
                  .map((response) => {
                    let data = response;


                     if (isPlatformServer(this.platformId)) {
                        this.transferState.set(TWITTER_KEY, data as any);
                      }
                    return data;
                  })
                  .catch((error) =>  Observable.throw(error) )

            }
      }

}
```

And the test the first tests are fine, but as soon as it hits the test for the error
'should return error if cannot get Tweets'
 I get the above error:

```
import { TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import {HttpClientTestingModule, HttpTestingController} from '@angular/common/http/testing';
import { BrowserTransferStateModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { SocialService } from './social.service';

describe('SocialService', () => {
  let httpMock: HttpTestingController;
  let service:SocialService;
  let apiURL:string
  let returnedResults:any
  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      providers: [SocialService],
      imports:[BrowserTransferStateModule, HttpClientTestingModule]
    });
    service = TestBed.get(SocialService);
    httpMock = TestBed.get(HttpTestingController);
    apiURL = 'https://server.herokuapp.com/';
    returnedResults = [{created_at: "Jul 16 2018", id: 1, id_str: "1", text: "Twitter text1"}, {created_at: "Jul 17 2018", id: 2, id_str: "2", text: "Twitter text2"}]
  });

  it('should be created', () => {
    expect(service).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it('should get Tweets', () => {
    service.initTwitter()
    .subscribe((response)=>{
      expect(response).toBeDefined();
      expect(response).toEqual(returnedResults);
      console.log(response)
    })
    const request = httpMock.expectOne(apiURL+'twitter/gettweets');
    expect(request.request.method).toEqual('GET');
    request.flush(returnedResults);
    httpMock.verify();
  });

  it('should return error if cannot get Tweets', () => {
    service.initTwitter()
    .subscribe((response)=>{
      expect(response).toBeDefined();
      expect(response.failure.error.type).toBe('ERROR_GETTING_TWEETS');   
    })
    const request = httpMock.expectOne(apiURL+'twitter/gettweets');
    request.error(new ErrorEvent('ERROR_GETTING_TWEETS'));
    httpMock.verify();
  });
});
```

Comment: If you throw an error in observable that ends up in the *second* callback to subscribe.

Comment: Thanks so much for that, it worked, I've posted, how I've changed the code in an answer, but if you want to post your comment as an answer I'll mark it as correct

Answer (score 5):

Thanks to @jonrsharpe, here's what I'm doing now

```
 it('should return error if cannot get Tweets', () => {
        service.initTwitter()
        .subscribe(()=>{
        }, error =>{
          expect(error.error.type).toBe('ERROR_GETTING_TWEETS'); 
          console.log(error.error.type) 
          Observable.throw(error)
        }
      ) 
        const request = httpMock.expectOne(apiURL+'twitter/gettweets');
        request.error(new ErrorEvent('ERROR_GETTING_TWEETS'));
        httpMock.verify();
      });
```